# Splitting a long row into multiple shorter rows in R

Tags: r

I have this really wide data frame (1 obs. of 696 variables) and i want to split this only row into others every 10 columns

I think it'd be too confusing to post just the final data because it is too wide, so I'm giving the code for how I created it

```
library(tidyverse)

Vol_cil <-  function(r, h) {
  vol <- (pi*(r^2))*h
  return(vol)}

vec <-  Vol_cil(625, 0:695)/1000000

df <- data.frame(vec)

stckovrflw <- df %>% 
  mutate("mm" = 0:695) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = mm, values_from = vec)
```

I want the columns to go from 0 to 9 and the rows from 0 to 69, with the data in this data frame (stckovrflw), I tried to find anyway to do this in the internet but couldn't do anything, ended up exporting it to excel and doing it by hand.

I'd appreciate any help

If I wasn't able to make myself understood please feel free to ask me anything

Comment: 695 is not a multiple of 9, it seems  what you want is a matrix, you could get it with `matrix(c(stckovrflw),byrow=TRUE,ncol=9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. It starts by putting `stckovrflw` back to long format so if that is actually what you have you can take out that step. It works by creating columns for the row and column number, then spreading by column number.

```
stckovrflw %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to='mm') %>% 
  mutate(row=rep(1:70, each=10)[1:696], col=rep(1:10, 70)[1:696]) %>% 
  select(-mm) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from='col', values_from='value')
```